# Objects are not valid as a React child error when adding elements

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a react app that have a list o food itens, and i can add them to a cart, my for some reason every time that a i try to add something to the card, the app crashes and the message error appear:

"*Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, price, amount, key}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.*"

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import FoodList from './Components/Foods/FoodList'
import Header from './Components/Header/Header'
import Cart from './Components/Cart/Cart';
import CartContext from './Contexts/CartContext';

function App() {

  const [cartVisibility,setCartVisibility] = useState(false);
  const [cartItems,setCartItems] = useState([]);

  function cartVisibilityHandler(){
    setCartVisibility(prev => {
      return (!prev);
    });
  }

  function addCartItem(name,price,amount){
    setCartItems((prev) => {
      const itemFinded = prev.find((item) => item.name === name);
      if(itemFinded){
        return prev.map(item => (
          item.name === name ? {...item, amount: item.amount + amount} : item
        ));
      }else{
        return [
          ...prev,
          {
            name: name,
            price: price,
            amount: amount,
            key: Math.random(),
          },
        ];
      }
    });
    
  }

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{
      cartItems : cartItems,
      addCartItem: addCartItem
    }}>
      
        <Header cartVisibilityHandler={cartVisibilityHandler}></Header>
        <FoodList></FoodList>
        {cartVisibility && <Cart cartVisibilityHandler={cartVisibilityHandler}></Cart>}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
 import './FoodList.css'
 import FoodItem from "./FoodItem";
 
 
 function FoodList(props){
    return(
        <div className="food-list-container">
            <FoodItem name="Pao de Queijo" info="pao feito com queijo gostoso" price="10 R$"></FoodItem>
            <FoodItem name="Queijo" info="feito de vaca" price="10 R$"></FoodItem>
            <FoodItem name="Teu pai" info="aquele viado" price="10 R$"></FoodItem>
        </div>
    )
 }

 export default FoodList;
```

```
import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react';
import CartContext from '../../Contexts/CartContext';
import './FoodItem.css'

function FoodItem(props){

    const [amount,setAmount] = useState(0);

    const ctx = useContext(CartContext);

    function amountChangeHandler(event){
        setAmount(event.target.value);
    }

    function addButtonHandler(event){
        ctx.addCartItem(props.name, props.price,+amount);   
    }

    return(
        <div className="food-container">
            <div>
                <div className='food-title'>{props.name}</div>
                <div className='food-info'>{props.info}</div>
                <div className='food-price'>{props.price}</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div className='amount-container'>
                    <div className='amount-title'>Amount</div>
                    <input type="number" min="0" value={amount} onChange={amountChangeHandler}></input>
                </div>
                <button className='add-button' onClick={addButtonHandler}>+Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default FoodItem;
```

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import './Cart.css';
import CartContext from '../../Contexts/CartContext';
import CartItem from './CartItem';


function Cart(props){

    const ctx = useContext(CartContext);


    function cartClickHandler(){
        props.cartVisibilityHandler();
    }

    const cartItems = ctx.cartItems.map((item) => (
        <CartItem item={item} key={item.key}/>
    ));

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className='modal-centralizer'>
                <div className='modal-container'>
                    {cartItems}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div onClick={cartClickHandler} className='modal-background'></div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Cart;
```

```
import './CartItem.css';

function CartItem({props}){
    const { name, price, amount } = props.item;
    return(
        <div>
            <div>{name}</div>
            <div>{price}</div>
            <div>{amount}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CartItem;
```

I checked if somehow i tried to render a object but i cant find it, even chatGPT cant

Comment: This is very easy to debug without ChatGPT, simply add/remove places where you render `{data}` until you find the one that fixes the issue. Also get in the habit of using console.log() to debug your code. One problem you have is `function CartItem({props})` should be `function CartItem(props)`

Comment: I tried that before, the only thing that stops the bug is when deleted is the addCartItem function in the app component, i'm looking at it but cannot figure it out